# Different gate resistors to turn on and turn off a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I found that people use different gate resistors to turn on and turn off a MOSFET as shown below. Is there any reason behind this?

Usually, the turn on resistor is higher than the turn off resistor. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Asymmetric gate resistors are appropriate for asymmetric loads.  For example, a converter that is ZCS at turn-on but ZVS at turn-off.  A DCM flyback converter, for example.

It can also be a good reason for EMI and even functional reasons (reducing peak turn-on current, and corresponding overshoot voltage due to switching loop inductance) in converters that are nominally ZVS (e.g. half-bridge LLC), because they have to start up at least once, some time, somehow, and a gentler rising edge is helpful for that.  Meanwhile, the slow turn-on in normal ZVS operation has little effect because the transistor might be indeed reverse-biased (body diode conduction) during turn-on, so as long as it's turned on by the time the load current becomes forward again, it's fine.

It can also be used in hard-switched converters, as a means to tweak dead time.  Gate pulses should normally not overlap, to avoid direct cross-conduction, but turning both off (such as in a synchronous buck converter) forces body diode conduction and subsequent hard-switched diode reverse recovery, which costs significant switching losses, or can increase EMI.  Reducing deadtime improves this.  The same reason also applies by symmetry in a class D amplifier, where load voltage and current may be independent (reactive load, or inverter/synchronous rectifier for grid-connected application), and therefore neither (rising or falling) switching edge should have significant dead time.

This answer throws around a lot of terms at once, and familiarity with common SMPS topologies is suggested.  The keywords are excellent starting points for further reading.

Comment: I don't understand the usefulness of a 10 Ohms resistor. Shouldn't it be at least 100 Ohms to have a protective effect?

Comment: Compare the output impedance of the gate driver, its speed, and the gate charge and internal resistance of the transistor.

Comment: @Fredled Why do you think there's some magic threshold at 100 Ω? 100 Ω would actually be way too much for most switching converters, unless they're operating at extremely low frequencies.

Comment: @Hearth I'm not even sure about "most"; with Crss being reduced so extraordinarily these days, the output switching speed (delta V or delta I / delta t) can be shockingly fast, even with quite slow dVgs/dt. As a practical matter (optimizing for efficiency), somewhat smaller values do tend to be preferred though. But yeah, depends entirely on the scale factor.

Comment: @Hearth But in this case why do put a resistor in the first place? I understand that it's a trade off between protection and speed, but does 10 ohms still protect something?

Comment: @Fredled Yes, if 10 Ω is enough to damp the oscillations you're trying to damp. I've used 1 Ω gate resistors before (and they were absolutely necessary; the FETs didn't survive long without them).